# Copy mesh thousand times and animate without big performance hit?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, webgl

I have a demo where i used hundreds of cubes that have exactly same geometry and texture, example:

```
texture  = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture ...
material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( map: texture )
geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 )

cubes = []
for i in [0..1000]
  cubes.push new THREE.Mesh geometry, material

... on every frame

for cube in cubes
  // do something with each cube
```

Once all the cubes are created i start moving them on the screen.

All of them have the same texture, same size, they just change position and rotation. The problem here is that when i start using many hundreds of cubes the computer starts to suffer to render it.

Is there any way i could tell Three.js / WebGL that all those objects are the same object, they are identical copies just in different positions ?

I ready something about BufferGeometry and Geometry2 being able to boost performance for this sort of situation but i'm not exactly sure what would be the best in this case.

Thank you

Comment: [Merging geometries in three.js](http://www.jbernier.com/merging-geometries-in-three-js) has a demo of 150000 moving cubes

Comment: I read on
http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/10/05/performance-merging-geometry/ "it won’t be possible to move the merged objects independantly from each othe" hence why i thought it wasn't possible to move them individually after. will try this any other ideas?

Comment: I haven't checked the code but the cubes look like they are moved independently

Comment: indeed! i haven't seen that example before, i'm having a look and seeing if that would be an option. the source surely isn't as simple as "shadow cloning" a mesh which would be ideal to keep my application as simple as it is. Does it need to be so low level just to tell Three.js / WebGL that the cubes, geometry and texture are the same ?

Comment: Sorry, but I have not worked with three.js/WebGL yet. That was just one of the more interesting search results - imho^^

Comment: You need to look into Instanced Geometry.Take a look at a demo http://alteredqualia.com/three/examples/webgl_cubes.html

Comment: how about http://blog.tojicode.com/2013/07/webgl-instancing-with.html

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way i could tell Three.js / WebGL that all those objects are the 
>   same object, they are identical copies just in different positions ?

Unfortunately there's nothing that can automatically determine and optimize rendercalls in that regard. That would be pretty awesome.

> I read something about BufferGeometry and Geometry2 being able to boost performance for this sort of situation but i'm not exactly sure what would be the best in this case.

So, the details here is this: the normal `THREE.Geometry`-class three.js provides is built for developer-convenience, but is a bit far from how data is handled by WebGL. This is what the `DirectGeometry` (earlier called Geometry2) and `BufferGeometry` are for. A BufferGeometry is a representation of how WebGL expects data for drawcalls to be held: it contains a typed-array for every attribute of the geometry. The conversion from `Geometry` to `BufferGeometry` happens automatically every time `geometry.verticesNeedsUpdate` is set to true.

If you don't change any of the attributes, this conversion will happen once per geometry (of which you have 1) so this is completely ok and moving to a buffer-geometry won't help (simply because you are already using it).

The main problem you face with several hundred geometries is the number of drawcalls required to render the scene. Generally speaking, every instance of `THREE.Mesh` represents a single drawcall. And those drawcalls are expensive: A single drawcall that outputs hundred thousands of triangles is no problem at all, but a thousands of drawcalls with 100 triangles each will very quickly become a serious performance problem.

Now, there are different ways how the number of drawcalls can be reduced using three.js. The first is (as already mentioned in comments) to combine multiple meshes/geometries into a single one (in the end, meshes are just a collection of triangles, so there's no requirement that they form a single "body" or something like that). This isn't too practical in your case as this would involve applying the position and rotation of each of your cubes via JS and update the vertex-arrays accordingly on each frame.

What you are really looking for is a WebGL-feature called geometry instancing. 
This is not as easy to use as regular meshes and geometries, but not too complicated either.

With instancing, you can create a huge amount of objects in a single drawcall. All  of the rendered objects will share a single geometry (your cube-geometry with its vertices, normals and uv-coordinates). The instancing happens when you add special attributes named `InstancedBufferAttribute` that can contain independent values for each of the instances. So you could add two per-instance attributes for position and rotation (or a single instance transformation-matrix if you like).

These examples should pretty much be what you are looking for:
http://threejs.org/examples/?q=instancing

The only difficulty with instancing as of now is the material: you will need to provide a custom vertex-shader that knows how to apply your per-instance-attributes to the vertex-positions from the original geometry (this can also be seen in the code of the examples).

Comment: Very nice detailed explanation, thank you.
You think a "quick and dirty" solution might be to merge all the geometries on each frame and try to execute only 1 draw call? That might be too much for the CPU i guess? it will take me some time to figure out the shader way, i'm totally new to shaders. will keep you guys posted

Comment: it might be worth trying, but i think you will quickly get to the problem that a) merging hundreds of geometries on every frame will produce a huge amount of garbage (causing more frequent and longer garbage-collection pauses) and b) will probably be a performance-problem recomputing the vertex-coordinates on every frame (although I'm always impressed how much you can actually do in plain javascript...). I'll see if I find the time to throw together a quick demo later.

Answer (score 3):

You have a webgl tag so Im going to give a non three js answer.

The best way to handle this is to allocate a float texture array made of model transform matrix data (or just vec3 positions if thats all you need). Then you allocate a mesh chunk containing all your cube data. You need to add an additional attribute which I refer to as `modelTransform index`. For each "cube instance" in the mesh chunk, write the correct `modelTransform index` value corresponding to the correct offset in the model transform data texture.

On each frame, you calculate the correct model transform data for all the cubes and write to the model transform data texture with correct offsets and such. Upload the texture to GPU on each frame.

In the vertex shader, access the model transform data from the `modelTransform index` attribute and the float texture. Rest is the same.

This is what I am using in my engine and it works well for smallish objects such as cubes. Note however, updating 150000 cubes on 60 FPS will likely take most of your CPU resources from JS. This is unavoidable regardless of which instancing scheme you take.

If the motion/animation of each cube is fixed, then a even better way to do it is to upload a velocity attribute and initial creation time stamp attribute for each cube instance. On each frame, send the current time as uniform and calculate the position as `"pos += attr_velocity * getDeltaTime(attr_initTime, unif_currentTime);"`. This skips work on CPU all together and allows you to render a much higher number of cubes.

Comment: thanks for your tips! definitely helped me understand this issue better